# Some WinAPI to check which process created a named pipe?

Tags: winapi, pipe, named-pipes

Is there some WinAPI call which would tell me who (which process) has created the named pipe?

*Note: Asking this questions, I have a feeling it "smells" somehow, and a proper design will be to communicate the process ID/handle using other means, however getting this information from the pipe itself would be simpler, and therefore if there is such API, I would probably still use it.*

Comment: no guarantee that a parent process exists anyway, because named pipes could have been created on another computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. And you are right about the smell.